# How to receive input from textfield to textarea and a lot more...?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, jtextarea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnma4.png)

How can I make it like that?
1) If user opens that program, you don't have to click on textfield to receive focus, instead, if you switch to that program, it immediatetly gives you a focus to write instead of clicking for focus.

2) If user writes a ID number or item name to textfield, textarea responds to textfield and shows that ID or name to the user, like, pops up.

3) How to make textarea smaller in case, that even panel shows out in corners? I'd like to make a textarea a little bit smaller like a box and outside a box, its just a gray color.

In order to fully help me, I'll gladly give out the code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public abstract class Itemlist extends JFrame implements ActionListener, FocusListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // create JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("small project");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(2);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setResizable(false);


        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.LEADING, 10, 10));
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

        JTextField tf = new JTextField(25);
        tf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 35));
        Font f = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 18);
        tf.setFont(f);
        panel.add(tf);
        frame.add(tf, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        tf.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                tf.getText();

            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                tf.setText("");

            }

        });

        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
        frame.add(ta);
        Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 16);
        ta.setEditable(false);
        ta.setFont(font);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(ta);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frame.add(scrollPane);

        BufferedReader br;
        String contents;

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/ItemList.txt"));
            contents = br.readLine();

            while ((contents = br.readLine()) != null) {


                ta.read(br, null);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }


        frame.pack();
        // frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    }
}
```

***All help is appreciated. Have been stuck on it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I suspect you want to consider using a [`WindowListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) and monitor for the `windowActivated` event, at which time you can call `requestFocusInWindow` on the `JTextField` to transfer focus to it automatically.  Focus management is a little bit of a black art, as it tends to work slightly differently on different platforms
2. I'm not sure entirely what you mean, but I'd look at the `ActionListener` support.  This will require the user to hit the "action" key (typically <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to trigger it.  If you want real time feedback, the a `DocumentListener` would be what you're looking for
3. Make use of the [`JTextArea`s constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea-int-int-) to specify the preferred number of rows and columns.  This will define the preferred scrollable size of the component, which will effect the size of the `JScrollPane` as well
4. In future, try and constrain you question to single, focused question, they are easier to answer and generally produce more detail